# 404 Not Found on sanctum/csrf-cookie path

Tags: laravel

So I've been building a projet based on laravel. I'm building on a SPA foundation with sanctum as my authorization package. It works perfectly. Then I deploy the project to the server and everytime I try to login there is a 404 error on /sanctum/csrf-cookie.
How could this happen? Is it because the SanctumServiceProvider not working.

[image: This is the error image]

Comment: But it works perfectly on localhost with SESSION_DDRIVER=file. Why is that a problem lad?

Comment: nope, the session domain is configurated to my host

Comment: It works on .test domain on my local development environment

Comment: done, i've put it in the thread

Comment: nope the project is on root folder... app is just a route inside my spa

Comment: then run `composer install`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is when you define sanctum prefix, the route become something else like this:

[image]

> you can check your routes with : `php artisan route:list`

as you can see the `/sanctum/` is removed and when you check the route `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` it will not be and throws 404 error. So you have two options:

- add this prefix:  `'prefix' => 'api/v1/sanctum'`
- or
- change GET call to `api/csrf-cookie`

Comment: where it must be added this 'prefix', wich file?

Comment: your_project/config/sanctum.php

Comment: I meet the same problem using axios from vuejs and when I check the routes  with php artisan route:list, the /sanctum/ is not removed and the route is sanctum/csrf-cookie ..... Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show. I don't see any reason why it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you're setting correct `axios defaults` for your `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` api call.

You can set it as follows

```js
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost"; //Before sending get request
    axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(async () => {
    //Logic to handle login
    });
```

If `defaults` are not set properly `url` becomes `http::localhost::8080/sanctum/crf-cookie` which is where frontend is serving but instead it has to be `http::localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie`

> Note: localhost example is just for explanation. For production server make sure your url is correct and api call is on backend.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding:

```
AllowOverride All
```

to the apache directory config

Answer (score 0):

add in last line inside **config/sanctum.php**

```
'routes' => false,
```

Answer (score -2):

Add in **config/cors.php**

'paths' => ['*']

Comment: please explian more about your solution

Comment: he is getting a problem related to route not found, not related to cors.

Comment: cores should be configered to 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],